# Is there a way to move a file and then change it in such a way that that git can still cleanly cherry-pick changes?

Tags: git

In CPython, the current implementation of the `datetime` module defines all the classes and methods of `datetime` in Python, then imports all that same stuff from a faster C implementation (the `_datetime` module), overriding or deleting all the Python implementations *if the C implementation is available*. This happens every time you `import datetime`, but that's pretty wasteful. We're hoping to [re-organize the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84976) so that `import datetime` first checks for the C implementation and, if it fails to import that, instead import from a `_pydatetime` module.

This is a simple enough change, but it comes at a maintenance cost — because we support older versions for several years, we generally work on the `main` branch and backport appropriate changes to older branches. We have [a bot](https://github.com/python/miss-islington) that uses git to automatically cherry-pick new PRs onto old branches.

The problem we're having is that when we [re-organize the code in this way](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/99090/files), `git` no longer seems to know that when I make changes to `Lib/_pydatetime.py`, I want the changes backported on to `Lib/datetime.py` in older branches. In [this branch](https://github.com/pganssle/cpython/tree/move_pydatetime), I have tried using two commits, one that moves `Lib/datetime.py` to `Lib/_pydatetime.py` and a second that re-introduces `Lib/datetime.py`, then introduced a change in `Lib/pydatetime.py`. When I try `git cherry-pick <commit-id>` (where `commit-id` is the head of the `move_pydatetime` branch), I get a merge conflict because `main` doesnt have a `Lib/pydatetime` branch.

My question for y'all git experts out there is: is there a strategy that will make it possible to cleanly cherry-pick changes in `Lib/_pydatetime.py` directly into the backport branches, or is there some reason that this cannot work *in principle*?

Ezio Melotti did [some investigations on strategies here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84976#issuecomment-1311243703), and could not find one that works.

Note: I am really only looking for answers that involve how I structure the commits when making this change, since I'm looking to avoid special-casing `Lib/_pydatetime.py` / `Lib/datetime.py` in the bot (if I can even do this). If there's no way to get `git` to understand natively that `Lib/_pydatetime.py` in the post-change world should map to Lib/datetime.py` in the pre-change world, I just want to know that that's true, and I will figure out workarounds (or manually backport all changes until the pre-change branches are all out of support — there are only a few of these each year).

*Edit*: The answers to [*Is it possible to move/rename files in Git and maintain their history?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history) hint that this may not be possible, but some say "yes" and other say "no", some involve rewriting history (which we cannot do here) and others focus on how to follow the history using `git log --folow`. They certainly *suggest* that this may not be possible, but do not specifically address how `git cherry-pick` works in such a way that I am confident saying, "Ah yes, there is no way to structure these changes to the repository in such a way that `git cherry-pick` cannot follow them."

I think the biggest additional wrinkle that this particular question adds is the fact that `Lib/datetime.py` will exist both before and after the change, but it will represent two fundamentally different files. I'm OK with changes to `Lib/datetime.py` not being backportable to before the change, but changes to `Lib/pydatetime.py` need to map to pre-change `Lib/datetime.py`.

Comment: Basically, no... you need two commits to preserve the history of the move/edit. If git can figure out the history, then it will usually handle cherry-picks just fine. The linked Question explains in more detail.

Comment: @JDB I'm fine with two commits (the linked branch has move and edit as two separate commits), but `cherry-pick` doesn't seem to see in the history the fact that `Lib/_pydatetime.py` had a commit where it was just moved from `Lib/datetime.py`.

Comment: You may need to try a different merge strategy as recommended in this post: [git cherry-pick with target file renamed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843857/git-cherry-pick-with-target-file-renamed)

Comment: @JDB I'm still getting the same problem with `-Xrename-threshold=10%` (though honesty `Lib/_pydatetime.py` should be >95% similar to `Lib/_datetime.py` anyway), plus, this question is "What is the best way to structure the commits to make this change", and for the purposes of the question I cannot change what the cherry-pick command is.

Comment: Ok... sounds like a more complex scenario than is normal. Apologies for the knee-jerk reaction. I'll read through more carefully.

Comment: For clarification... is it `Lib/_datetime.py` or `Lib/datetime.py`? You seem to be using them interchangeably in your question. I think it's supposed to be `Lib/datetime.py`

Comment: @JDB `Lib/datetime.py`, sorry the `_datetime.py` ones are just me being confused. I've edited the post to remove references to `Lib/_datetime.py`, which is not a file on either branch (the `_datetime` module comes from `Mod/datetimemodule.c` I think).

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that git uses a rename detection algorithm to guess renames when comparing two commits ; in my experience, there is an additional rule:

- if two commits have a file with same `path/to/file`, git will always try to map these two files together and never launch a "content detection" scan against other potential files

---

One workaround could be to choose a way to turn `datetime.py` into a stub in all branches, and have it import symbols from other files with distinct names.

An outline of what it could be (I am not familiar enough with cpython to understand the impacts of changing the source layout) :

```
### in legacy branch:

## datetime.py:

from ._legacy_datetime import *

## _legacy_datetime.py:
# the content of the original datetime.py
```

now, if you try to backport a change from `newbranch` where `_pydatetime.py` has been modified, and `_legacy_datetime` and `_pydatetime` are still similar enough, it should be changed to a patch which modifies `_legacy_datetime.py`.

---

Another workaround could be:

since you know for a fact that `_pydatetime.py` must me ported to `datetime.py`:
instead of just cherry-picking a commit, create by hand two commits where you explicitly renamed `_pydatetime.py` to `datetime.py`, and cherry-pick that.

A rough (untested) outline:

```
# instead of running `git cherry-pick eacf32`:

# create a "fake" commit with the content of *the parent* of target commit:

git checkout --orphan wip
# get the complete content for the parent of target commit:
git restore -SW -s eacf32^ -- .
# rename that specific file:
git mv Lib/_pydatetime.py Lib/datetime.py
# commit:
git commit -C eacf32^   # <- keep the same author date/author/message

# now create a "fake" commit with the content of the target commit:

git restore -SW -s eacf32 -- .
# rename that specific file:
git mv Lib/_pydatetime.py Lib/datetime.py
# commit:
git commit -C eacf32
```

`git show wip` should now display a patch which modifies `Lib/datetime.py` instead of `Lib/_pydatetime.py`

Please drop a comment if you need to "industrialize" that path renaming technique to a range of commits rather than a single commit, it can be scripted using `git filter-repo`.